# The width of int data type on a machine

Tags: c, integer-promotion

Is it right to say that the width of int data type depends on the data width of the ALU ? 
For example is it right to say that a 32-bit processor will have int data type as 32-bit wide?
Similarly for 16 bit and 8 bit(please note that C guarantees that the size of int at least [greater than 16 bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Basic_types)).

Comment: Many processors haven't had distinct ALUs for some time now, so you can't really use that as a reference. Instead it might be better to use the processor internal data-bus width.

Comment: check the link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331751/does-the-size-of-an-int-depend-on-the-compiler-and-or-processor

Comment: here is another, almost a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689049/what-decides-the-sizeof-an-integer

Comment: @peter thanks for the link. That contains a really good explanation of what i am asking. Please also consider the question in the light of 8-bit architectures.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg cant understand you properly. Please explain a bit more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is up to the implementation. For instance, many compilers for 64bit systems have 32bit wide ints still.

Comment: Also, 16-bit compilers were used in 386+ for a long time.

Comment: And 8-bit compilers typically have 16-bit ints.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably have to refer to you compiler's documentation regarding the determination of the size of a primitive type since the details of primitive types and built-in operators such as `sizeof` would be compiler-specific. In the end it probably would be directly correlated to the details of the hardware, but I believe C is at a higher level of abstraction than concerning yourself with ALU details.