# can someone explain me what is happening here for using malloc for pointer

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int * ptr=(int *)malloc(40);
    printf("%d",sizeof(ptr));
}
```

When I'm running this, output is coming as 8...what is happening here...why is output 8?

Comment: Because that's the size of `ptr`. What did you expect?

Comment: but when I give sizeof(int), system prints 4; but why is here size of pointer became 8..???

Comment: Just as a note: what you're doing is officially undefined behavior, because sizeof doesn't yield an `int`, but you've used `%d`, which tells `printf` that what you've passed is an int. Probably makes no difference though.

Comment: So that means, in a 64bit machine int size remains 4, but pointer size is 8...and in 32bit machine pointer size becomes 4...am i right..correct me if i am wrong..

Comment: You're wrong to assume the size of either of those things depends only on the 'bit-ness' of the machine. Though in most cases your assumption is correct for pointers, 'int' sizes are less consistent.

Comment: @user195661, Please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/2331768/67381 and  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10197339/67381 for your understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`malloc()` returns a pointer to 40 bytes of memory (probably 10 ints) and assigns it to `ptr`.  The reason `sizeof(ptr)` is 8 is because you are using a 64 bit machine and pointers are 8 bytes in size.

You should use `sizeof()` inside the `malloc()` because it's good form and avoids problems if the type ever changes size (crossing platforms or whatever).  If you really want space for 10 ints then use:

```
int *ptr = malloc(10 * sizeof *ptr);
```

This allocates 10 lots of the size of the type `ptr` points to, in this case `int`.  The benefit of doing this is you can change the type without changing the `malloc()`

Answer (score 2):

The `sizeof` operator is a compile time operator, and the size of any pointer is 8 bytes on your machine.

There is no way to retrieve the dynamic size of the `malloc`-ed memory zone. You have to know it otherwise, or to keep it somewhere.

You might consider using [Boehm's conservative garbage collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) then you'll call `GC_malloc` instead of `malloc`, you won't need to call `free` (or `GC_free`), and you could use `GC_size(p)` to get the approximate size of the previously `GC_malloc`-ed memory zone starting at `p` (but I don't recommend using `GC_size`).

If using `malloc` on Linux, learn how to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to hunt memory leak bugs, and compile with `gcc -Wall -g`

Answer (score 0):

The variable `ptr` is a pointer to int, an your system it happens to have the size of 8 byte.

Answer (score 0):

ptr is a pointer.its printing the size fo the pointer on your system.
as ptr holds an address, 8 bytes is the size required to hold an address on a 64 bit machine.
This is compiler specific.You cannot retrieve the size  allocated to a pointer.

if you getting this doubt,then you should also get a doubt of how does free() will free the memory without knowing the size that has been allocated to the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this on my Windows 32bit machine, i am getting ans 4 bytes, i think as ptr is a pointer to int show its showing the corre