# C interview puzzle with segfault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'v come across an C interview question. The question claims that the following code segfaults on ia64 but not on ia32. I don't think so. I also tested on an 64 bit Linux machine with gcc and it didn't crash at all.

```
int main()
{
    int* p;
    p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *p = 10;
    return 0;
}
```

What was the intended puzzle?

Comment: did he include any header? wrong malloc called i believe(hence UB)

Comment: My best guess is that the code is non-portable. If the code is compiled on an ia32 and attempts to run on an ia64 the segfault may occur.

Comment: ia64 != intel64. The latter being x86_64. ia64 is intel Itanium.

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197242/what-should-be-the-sizeofint-on-a-64-bit-machine .  sizeof(int) may not equal sizeof(int*).

Comment: It's supposed to be about unaligned memory returned from `malloc()`. If the address is not divisible by `sizeof(int)` then this will fail on ia64.  But I don't think any sane malloc would return unaligned memory.