# sizeof of an enum on 64 bit machine

Tags: c, enums

The standard says that an enum type is a integral type between `char`, `signed` and `unsigned`.

But an `int` into a 32 bit machine should be 4 byte and into a 64 bit machine should be 8 byte.
So why my GCC into a 64 bit machine returns 4 as `sizeof` of this enum?

```
enum color
{
  RED,
  GREEN,
  BLUE
};

size_t t = sizeof (enum color); // here 4
```

Comment: An the `sizeof(int)` isn't 4 on your machine?

Comment: Related: [type of enums](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113855/is-the-sizeofenum-sizeofint-always) and [size of int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197242/what-should-be-the-sizeofint-on-a-64-bit-machine)

Comment: On all common 64 bit ABIs `int` is 32 bit.

Comment: The size of an `int` is determined by a compiler. It is not necessarily the same as the word size of the machine.

Comment: The C Standard on this had been quoted here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1113869/694576

Comment: Your question description is full of false premisses. Another one: the standard doesn't mention `signed` or `unsigned`, but it speaks of signed or unsinged integer types. Also there is no thing like *the* word size on a modern machine. They have different types of registers with different width. The description of the ABI interface of modern architectures is complex. Voting to close this question, this leads nowhere.

Comment: `int` in 16-bit machine is commonly 16-bit while in 32-bit and 64-bit machine, it's commonly 32-bit. the size of `long` should be a better measure of the bit length of the machine but still not accurate.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: `sizeof(long)` is a very bad idea, because LLP64 is used is some platforms (like Windows, and at least one OS in the Unix family). `sizeof(void*)` (or `sizeof(uintptr_t)` for C99) is a far better measure.

Answer (score 4):

OP: The standard says that an enum type is a integral type between `char`, `signed` and `unsigned`.
A: Close, but not quite.  [See more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1113869/2410359) @alk

> Each enumerated type shall be compatible with `char`, a signed integer type, or an
>   unsigned integer type. The choice of type is implementation-defined, but shall be
>   capable of representing the values of all the members of the enumeration.   C11dr §6.7.2.2 4

OP: But an `int` on a 32 bit machine should be 4 bytes and on a 64 bit machine should be 8 bytes.
A: No.  Although common, a processor's word size and `int` are usually the same, the C spec does not require that and many implementations do not follow that especially with compilers on 64-bit machines using 32-bit `int`.  Also 8-bit processors (still common in 2014 in the embedded world) would need at least an 16-bit `int` to be compliant.

OP:why does GCC on a 64 bit machine return 4 as `sizeof` of this enum?
A: It's the compiler's choice.  Likely to match an `int` size, fairly common with 64-bit compilers.

Comment: His compiler is using LP64 programming model I think. And in it, int is of 32-bits if I am not wrong.